# Sequelize is adding foreign keys. How can I delete and prevent future occurences

Tags: sequelize.js

I am having some issues with a database that I am working on. Looking at pgAdmin, I see several foreign keys that seem to be duplicates like races_election_id_fkey, races_election_id_fkey1, races_election_id_fkey2, etc.

I don't have a constraint with that name. The text races_election_id appears nowhere in my back end. How did this get created?

Why is is creating multiple copies instead of using the old one or giving me an error?

How do I prevent this in the future?

[image]

Comment: Please add model definitions and their associations